# What is a faster way to backup and restore a MySQL DB than mysqldump? (faster than 4 hours)

Tags: database, virtual-machine, virtual-pc, database-backups, vhd

We have a database that is about 3GB (in text) after `mysqldump` is used to dump a text representation of it, and then

```
mysql < mysqlstatement.sql
```

is used to restore the database.  But it takes 4 hours.

Is there a way to quickly back up / restore the database instead?

It is on a Mac using Ruby on Rails, so one time I set the `test` environment to use the development DB, and the test wiped out the whole DB in a few seconds.

I have a way which is to "take a snapshot" of the development environment if it is PC -- just use Virtual PC and say the virtual disk image is only 2, 3GB, then we can save that virtual hard drive (VHD), and then the whole thing together with the DB is backed up.

But on Mac, there is no such way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the database's storage engine is MyISAM, it's safe just to copy the files, and copy them back when needed. With InnoDB it's more complicated. Take a look at [Percona's xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/)

Answer (score 0):

The DB is just a directory (or maybe a file with some engines...), nothing prevents you to backup it. It is named after the name of the DB and is located in mysql's `datadir` (check **my.cnf**).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend xtrabackup if you are using Innodb tables.

mydumper is also an alternative that might give you some performance improvements- http://www.mydumper.org/